# install.packages("knitr") leads to error untar2: incomplete block on file and installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to get RMarkdown running but I ultimately always end up with the following error message when executing

`install.packages("knitr")`

```
Fehler in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status
Fehler in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
```

When researching to solve this problem, I found this article [https://lcolladotor.github.io/2019/09/18/windows-user-space-issues-with-installing-r-packages/][1] , but I am not sure if it really applies to my problem (although my windows username consists of firstname and lastname). I tried the second alternative (reinstalling r and changing the location), but this method did not work for me even R is now saved under C:\R-3.6.1.

It is my first question to ask in stackoverflow, so tell me if you need more information. Thank you very much in advance!

Informations concerning my setup:

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)
```

`rstudioapi::versionInfo()`

```
$version
[1] ‘1.2.5019’`
```

Comment: *"incomplete block on file"* to me sounds like a corrupted download. Try downloading the [`xfun`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xfun/index.html)  file manually, then `install.packages("xfun_0.11.tar.gz")`. If it continues, try `untar("xfun_0.11.tar.gz"), list=TRUE)` to see if it's solely within that step of it. (I just did that on my win10 box and it worked without error, hope it does for you too.)

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans! Getting the files manually and installing them in RStudio over Tools -> Install Packages... -> Install from Package Archive File solved the problem! So relieved, spend so many hours yesterday trying to solve this thing...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me.
After unzipping the package file simply get the final folder out of the unzipped folder and then specify the path. Usually after unzipping, two folders get created, first one contains same second folder but it is only second folder that contains the package. get the second one out of the first and delete the first one. after deletion, specify the path.